# Strange display issues in Virtual Box 5.02 + Xuntubu 15.04 + Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am writing some C code in a Xubuntu VM.
The IDE is Eclipse Mars.
When I move the horizontal scroll bar. The display starts to look awesome!

This only happens in the editor window. And if I switch the tabs, the display recovers.

[image]

Anyone met such issue?

### ADD 1 - Some context.

- Host OS: Win7 64bit SP1 Build 7601
- Guest OS: Xubuntu 15.04 32bit
- Virtual Box: 5.02 32bit
- Eclipse: Mars

And the issue can be reproduced steadily.

### Add 2   - Issue solved!

Thanks to **@greg-449**. According to [472702](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472702#c1):

> This sounds like it might be a GTK3 issue which is now the default in
>   Mars. You can force GTK2 but setting the SWT_GTK3=0 environment
>   variable.

For how to set permanent system environment variables, check here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: Clearly, you're coding at WARP-SPEED. Uhmm, maybe provide what version of related packages/os version? That might be a place to start searching as a known bug. But I think this is off-topic for SO, as this is _not_ a programming issue.

Comment: @CollinDriscoll Problems with coding tools such as Eclipse are on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @greg-449 Good to know; thanks!

Comment: Sounds similar to Eclipse bug [472702](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472702) There is a suggestion there to switch to GTK2

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks! Switching to GTK2 solved my issue! If you post it as answer, I will mark it. Currently I just record in my original thread.

Comment: It worked here as well! Thanks!